# Kafka dumping log message doesn't show payload

Tags: apache-kafka

I am dumping Kafka Log messages to see what's within the log files. However, it doesn't show any PayLoad.

Would someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

see this

```
[gaurang.shah@hadoop_dev]$ cat 00000000000000000002.log
?B�i%f��i%f����������������testingD9�6pi%u%4i%u%4��������������$llllllllllll[gaurang.shah@hadoop_dev]$
[gaurang.shah@hadoop_dev]$ /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files 00000000000000000002.log --print-data-log
Dumping 00000000000000000002.log
Starting offset: 2
baseOffset: 2 lastOffset: 2 baseSequence: -1 lastSequence: -1 producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 partitionLeaderEpoch: 0 isTransactional: false position: 0 CreateTime: 1551110670527 isvalid: true size: 75 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE crc: 507646879
baseOffset: 3 lastOffset: 3 baseSequence: -1 lastSequence: -1 producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 partitionLeaderEpoch: 0 isTransactional: false position: 75 CreateTime: 1551111628084 isvalid: true size: 80 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE crc: 970929776
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use following command: (add `--deep-iteration` flag)

`/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files 00000000000000000002.log --deep-iteration --print-data-log`

Since v2.0, when `--print-data-log` flag is passed `deep-iteration` is enabled by default.